# Is there a shortcut for View Source in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

In Firefox or Chrome, I can do "Ctrl+U" to view source of a page. Is there such shortcut for IE9? (There are Developer Tools under F12 but that is something different, I just want the view source command).

Comment: Try ALT+V+C. I can't actually try it as I'm on a Mac ATM - but I think it should work..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no real shortcut that I'm aware of. The quickest way to access this feature is through the menu:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Can't view source if the menu is removed, but you can use developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) to review the active DOM.